# Google playstore app name space

Tags: android

Can any one have idea about how playstore search app name in android device ?
Problem is suppose my app name is "AndroidTest" with no spaces in name if I am seaching in playstore like "AndroidTest" than it will show my app if I am giving space in "Android Test" than it will not appear so is there any way I can optimize my app name in playstore app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question on programming

Comment: @AlexanderFarber suggest another forum for it, bc I think it's right place for such question

Comment: Sure, contact Google support with the question, how their store search is implemented

Comment: @AlexanderFarber would be much better, if answer were here, so anyone could read and not wait for answer from support

Comment: No, such an answer would be misleading, based on speculations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information.